# In ADO.NET, why is DataRow.SetNull() "protected"?

Tags: c#, ado.net

- In ADO.NET, `System.Data.DataRow.SetNull()` method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.setnull.aspx) is `protected`.
- If I have a generic/non-typed/non-derived `DataRow` I have to use `dataRow[dataColumn] = Convert.DBNull` to *set* it.
- On the other hand, to *test* for `DBNull` I can use any of the `public` overloads for `DataRow.IsNull()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull.aspx).

Does anyone know *why*/rationale for this?  Why don't MS make `DataRow.SetNull()` be `public` (and for that matter have the same overloads as `DataRow.IsNull()`)?